# How do I validate an XML string against an XSD file?

Tags: xml, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, xsd

My function below blows up on the XDocument constructor. Saying that non-whitespace characters are not allowed.

```
public static bool ValidateXML(string xml, string xsd)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    bool blnReturn = true;
    bool errors = false;
    XmlSchemaSet schemas = new XmlSchemaSet();
    schemas.Add("", XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xsd)));
    XDocument xmlDoc = new XDocument(XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xml)));

     //validate the XML text against the XSD
     xmlDoc.Validate(schemas, (o, e) =>
     {
          sb.AppendLine(e.Message);
          errors = true;
     });

     //if there are errors, display them and return false
     if (errors)
     {
         MessageBox.Show("XML did not parse cleanly. Please fix the following errors.\n\n" + sb.ToString(), "XML Parsing Results");
         blnReturn = false;
     }
     else
     {
         MessageBox.Show("XML Parsed cleanly. Saving to file.", "XML Parsing Results");
     }

     return blnReturn;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong with the code. It's likely that your xml string is invalid. Non-whitespace character error indicates that you have text characters "between" your xml elements. Ex:

```
<blah>This text is okay</blah>This text isn't
<blah>More text</blah>
```

Comment: I double checked the text being inserted into the function by pasting into W3Schools XML validator. It validates cleanly. Could it be because its pulling from an RTF control and may have invisible formatting characters?

Comment: I think you may have answered your own question. Create a unit test passing in your "valid" xml directly and see if it works.